# Scipyで、非零の要素が−1.0から1.0の一様分布で、ランダムなスパース行列を生成したい

Tags: python, scipy

Scipyで、非零の要素が−1.0から1.0の一様分布で、
ランダムなスパース行列を生成したいです。

単純に、Scipyのrandを用いて

```
scipy.sparse.rand(m, n)
```

と書くと、要素は0.0から1.0の一様分布なので、
非零の値がすべて正になってしまいます。

ランダムなスパース行列の生成の際に、
非零要素値の上限下限を変える
効率の良い方法はあるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

−1.0 から 1.0 の一様分布との事ですので、以下ではどうでしょうか。`[0, 1]` なので、`ceil()` が 1.0 になることを利用しています。

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sp
>>> r = sp.rand(100, 100)
>>> r2 = r * 2.0 - r.ceil()
>>> print r2
(0, 18)  0.105084065469
(0, 96)  -0.667551576265
(3, 60)  0.239045542473
(5, 38)  -0.420674130882
(5, 87)  0.146186464011
(6, 20)  -0.394829441002
               :
```

Comment: こちらのコードの方も試してみます。実際には1万×1万くらいのもっと大きな疎行列を考えておりまして、速度を比較してみたいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

`scipy.sparse.random`であれば非零要素を生成する乱数生成器を引数に渡せますので[-1,1] の一様分布の生成器`scipy.stats.uniform(loc=-1, scale=2).rvs`をつかって．

```
import scipy.stats
import scipy.sparse

rvs = scipy.stats.uniform(loc=-1, scale=2).rvs  # U(loc, loc+scale)
x = scipy.sparse.random(10, 5, density=0.1, data_rvs=rvs)
```

手元の結果は

```
(0, 1)  -0.351716913146
(8, 0)  -0.308927730864
(9, 2)  0.0949004467739
(5, 4)  0.621192454634
(8, 4)  -0.310937542874
```

となりました．

Comment: とても助かりました。下の方の回答も合わせて、速度を比較してみたいと思います。ありがとうございます。